# Use writeToUrl to update a file included in the build (in application container .app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to update SSL certificate dynamically using writeToUrl but I get this error :

```
// Returns the first certificate in the cert chain
SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0);

// Returns a DER representation of a certificate given a certificate object.
NSData * remoteCertificateData = CFBridgingRelease(SecCertificateCopyData(certificate));

NSError *error;
BOOL didUpdateCertif = [remoteCertificateData writeToURL:localCertificateUrl options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

The value of `localCertificateUrl` is something like `file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/79A3FE24-FA18-4DB9-9DDD-ED2135B47C5A/App-Name.app/certificate.cer`.

But I get this error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “certif.cer” in the folder “App-Name”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/79A3FE24-FA18-4DB9-9DDD-ED2135B47C5A/App-Name.app/certif.cer, NSUnderlyingError=0x170249ae0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

Is it something I am not doing right or It's not possible to update files included in the build dynamically?

Comment: *.. or It's not possible to update files included in the build dynamically*. Yes, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes I just found out that `You cannot write to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your app from launching.` [Link to official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that `You cannot write to this directory. To prevent tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time. Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your app from launching.`

[Link to official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)